# os.system() invoking doesnt work when used with other function modules such as pandas(python)

Tags: python, pandas, os.system

i am trying to execute a command for an executable file in Python using `os.system()` and accesing admin Rights.

This is the Code which works prefectly

```
import ctypes, sys
def is_admin():
 try:
    return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
 except:
    return False

if is_admin():
 import os
 os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(r'C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXXX')))
 #print(os.getcwd())
 a= 4331
 os.system( r'XXX.exe --file "input_directory" --output "Output_directory" --start {} --end {}'.format(a,a))

else:
# Re-run the program with admin rights
 ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

But if I try to run the same Code instead of giving input for variable-a when loaded from Pandas dataframe and load the value for the variable like the following below

```
import ctypes, sys
def is_admin():
 try:
    return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
 except:
    return False

if is_admin():
   import pandas as pd
   df=pd.read_excel(r'D:XXXX',sep=',')
   for i in df['framenumber']:
    import os
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(r'C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXXX')))

#print(os.getcwd())
    os.system( r'XXXX.exe --file "input_directory" --output "Output_directory" --start {} --end {}'.format(i,i))


else:
# Re-run the program with admin rights
 ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

This is not working when i take the input(variable for from Pandas. I cannot get why? Any solution?

Comment: You should check the precise type and value of `i`. Use `print(i)`, `print(repr(i))` and `print(type(i))`. Could you edit the question and provide us with this information?

Comment: i is a float and in the executable command line it accepts int, float. but still it does not work. I cannot find out why

Comment: That's not the exact answer I was looking for. Please do `print(r'XXXX.exe --file "input_directory" --output "Output_directory" --start {} --end {}'.format(i,i))` and check if the command looks as it should.

Comment: @Matthias I found out where the Problem is but still I cannot understand the reason, when i write my whole program of data extraction from Pandas to .exe execution in the else loop it works.